# Build Group cannot build the main project together with the language project in Delphi

Tags: delphi, localization

I create a project in Delhi XE3. Then add a language project to it. I hope I can create a build group that will build both the main project and the language project in the same configuration.

So I create a new build group, then add the main project, i.e., Project1, then I will see the language project is added automatically. That seems great:

[image]

But the problem is when I build the build group, only the main project is built, the language project is not. I still need to manually build the language project. Thus the build group is completely meaningless.

I try to click the empty fields for CHS language project, but get the following empty boxes:

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have not used the "Show Build Groups pane", but I often use (in the "Project Manager") the popup menu on "ProjectGroup1" and select "Build All" (alternatively on main menu "Project" - "Build All Projects") and then all projects are built. Just tested with 2 language projects added to a project, and all three were built (the date time of the EXE file and the RES files were all changed)

Comment: @TomBrunberg, But thus I need to manually select the configuration to "Release" or "Debug" before building, while build group is a predefined set of the build tasks.

Comment: Well, you said: *...only the main project is built, the language project is not* But sure yes, you need to know and select whether you want to debug or release your project. I responded to what you claimed is a problem.

Comment: @TomBrunberg, Thank you. Yes, your solution solves the problem in not able to build main project and the language project together.

Comment: Have you tried activating the configuration and platform by clicking on the now empty fields in the CHS row?

Comment: @UweRaabe, yes, I try, but both are empty. I have updated the post to show the empty boxes